do Rails Active Job support backoff retry strategies?
Does Rails ActiveJob support below retry strategies ?

Linear Backoff
Linear backoff involves waiting for a progressively increasing fixed interval between retry attempts.

Linear Jitter Backoff
Linear jitter backoff modifies the linear backoff strategy by introducing randomness to the retry intervals. This strategy still increases the delay linearly but adds a random "jitter" to each interval.

Exponential Backoff
Exponential backoff involves increasing the delay between retries exponentially. The interval might start at 1 second, then increase to 2 seconds, 4 seconds, 8 seconds, and so on, typically up to a maximum delay. This approach is more aggressive in spacing out retries than linear backoff.

Exponential Jitter Backoff
Exponential jitter backoff combines exponential backoff with randomness. After each retry, the backoff interval is exponentially increased, and then a random jitter is applied. The jitter can be either additive (adding a random amount to the exponential delay) or multiplicative (multiplying the exponential delay by a random factor).



You can create any strategy you need by passing a proc as a :wait option:
# Linear Backoff
retry_on Timeout::Error, wait: ->(executions) { executions * 10 }

# Linear Jitter Backoff
retry_on Timeout::Error, wait: ->(executions) { 
  seconds = executions * 10
  jitter = 0.3
  seconds + seconds * rand * jitter
}

# Exponential Backoff
retry_on Timeout::Error, wait: ->(executions) { 2 ** executions }

# Exponential Jitter Backoff
retry_on Timeout::Error, wait: ->(executions) { 
  seconds = 2 ** executions
  jitter = 0.3
  seconds + seconds * rand * jitter
}

Note that there is a separate :jitter option which does not apply when :wait is a proc.

:wait - Re-enqueues the job with a delay specified either in seconds (default: 3 seconds), as a computing proc that takes the number of executions so far as an argument, or as a symbol reference of :polynomially_longer, which applies the wait algorithm of ((executions**4) + (Kernel.rand * (executions**4) * jitter)) + 2 (first wait ~3s, then ~18s, then ~83s, etc)

https://api.rubyonrails.org/v7.1.3.4/classes/ActiveJob/Exceptions/ClassMethods.html#method-i-retry_on
